# Drupal Sub Sites with or without Aegir

Tags: aegir, subsites

We're currently using Aegir to manage sites, essentially, domains and sub domains. However, we have a need for sub sites. For e.g., domain.com would the parent, and the children sites would be domain.com/division1, domain.com/division2 and so. The databases could be the shared or not; themes could have a parent-child relationship or not. Looks like this is not in Aegir yet ([although the university crowds are asking for it](http://drupal.org/node/705026#comment-4907414))

What options exists to create and manage sub sites using Drupal? How do folks typically do this? I looked at the subsite module, while looks like it is still in dev for D7.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions. We've decided to stick with Ægir's functionality for now, and see where that gets us.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal sites in subdirectories are now fully supported in Aegir 2.x since [version 2.0](http://community.aegirproject.org/2.0)

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module to do what your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This very question was brought up during DrupalCon Chicago when the Aegir maintainers were present. Their answer was that they didn't want to support this because it's a generally bad idea, and instead subdomains should be used.